# Laravel 8 error on vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Configuration.php

Tags: php, jwt, laravel-8

**syntax error, unexpected 'Parser' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)", "exception": "ParseError", vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Configuration.php", "line": 22**

I have PHP 8.0 and composer v2.0 installed.

The project work locally using xampp perfectly but showing this error in Ubuntu 20.04, nginx config on Digtalocean

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to review the following how-to resources: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Complete Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same exact err, causing a 500 internal server error.

by adding `"lcobucci/jwt": "^3.3.3"` to my `composer.json` fixed the issue.

It's mostly dependencies issue, first I downgraded my laravel/passport from 10.1 to 10.0 in my `composer.json`
and my laravel/framework from 8.22.1 to 8.21.0 as it was working fine at that point.

```sh
vm:~$ php -v
PHP 7.4.13 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2020 06:24:43) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

my `composer.json` now looks like this,

```json
"laravel/framework": "^8.14",
"laravel/passport": "^10.1",
"lcobucci/jwt": "^3.3.3",
```

```sh
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v10.1.0
    - Installation request for laravel/passport ^10.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[10.x-dev, v10.1.0].
    - Conclusion: remove lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3
    - laravel/passport 10.x-dev requires lcobucci/jwt ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[3.4.x-dev, 4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[3.4.x-dev, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[4.0.x-dev, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[4.1.x-dev, 3.3.3].
    - Installation request for lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[3.3.3].
```

added

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 4 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating lcobucci/jwt (3.3.3 => 3.4.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating league/oauth2-server (8.1.1 => 8.2.4): Loading from cache
  - Updating laravel/framework (v8.21.0 => v8.22.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating laravel/passport (v10.0.0 => v10.1.0): Loading from cache
```

Now it's working just fine, you can find [more details here](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/1381)

Answer (score 1):

I did `composer install --no-plugins` and it fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and fixed it with composer update. May u try it too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).